# Скрипт на jquery не исполняется в google chrome / при обновлении ctrl+f5 в mozilla firefox

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Есть сайт, на котором фон, для правильного растягивания, изменяет размер с помощью этого скрипта:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#mBg').width('').css('display','none').height($(document).height());
    if($('#mBg').width()<$(document).width())
        {
            $('#mBg').height('auto').width($(document).width());
            $('#mBgC').height($(document).height())
        }
    $('#mBg').css({
        'display':'block',
        'left':-Math.round(($('#mBg').width()-$(document).width())/2)
        });
});
$(document).ready(function(){$(window).resize()})
```

Скрипт работает во всех браузерах (включая `IE`), но при обновлении через `ctrl+f5` в Мозиле, скрипт вообще не исполняется. Так же он вообще не работает в Хроме.

Пример: [amazin.ru](http://amazin.ru)

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как бы этого ни хотелось, document не представляет из себя ни canvas, ни размер видимой части экрана.
Видимо это и используется в jQuery. 
`document.documentElement.clientWidth` и `document.documentElement.clientHeight` возвращают именно viewport. Используйте их.

Answer (score 2):

Блииин, ну и код...

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var body = $(window), body_w = body.width(), body_h = body.height();
    var mbg = $('#mBg').width('').height(body_h);
    if(mbg.width() < body_w)
    {
        mbg.height('auto').width(body_w);
        $('#mBgC').height(body_h);
    }
    mbg.css({
        'display': 'block',
        'left': Math.round((body_w - mbg.width())/2)
    });
});
$(function(){$(window).resize()});
```

Слегка поправил. А вообще, вы хотите сделать фон высотой с window и посередине?

Comment: Суть скрипта — полностью заполнять документ фоновой картинкой, т.к. `{background-size:cover}` некоректно работает.

----

Ваш скрипт не работает, т.к. он заполняет только видимую часть документа, а при прокрутке появляется белый фон.